# Is it possible to convert a JMS TextMessage to a BytesMessage?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, mq

I am currently using IBM MQ and receiving messages. The message is being sent as a `javax.jms.TextMessage`, and I don't have control over it. The messages being sent are quite big, and I need my application to run within a certain amount of memory. Therefore, I don't want to load the entire message body into memory. Is there anyway to convert/accept the message as a `javax.jms.BytesMessage`? My aim is to basically use an output stream and send the data to a file so I don't have to keep it in memory and save space.

```java
@JmsListener(...)
public void receiveMessage(TextMessage m){
   String s = m.getText() // taking lot of memory
}
```

Comment: Also, do you have a heap dump from one of your OutOfMemoryErrors? If so, what is taking up the bulk of the memory?

Comment: I believe it's mainly the TextMessage object

Comment: Did you try eliminating Spring and just using the JMS API directly? That might free enough memory to do what you need.

Comment: Hi so sorry I tried to upvote your answer but apparently I don't have enough credits to do that. Currently I am trying your other suggestion where I don't use a spring boot application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* technically possible to convert the message, but it is almost certainly not going to help you if you do it in your memory-limited environment.

Any conversion process on the client will involve reading the body `String` of the `javax.jms.TextMessage` and copying it to the body of the `javax.jms.BytesMessage` as a `byte[]`. However, then you will have 2 copies of the data in memory at the same time which seems to be exactly what you're trying to avoid.

If you have another environment with access to more memory then you could write an application whose *only* job was to convert these messages and then send them to a new queue where your memory-limited application could then read them.

Answer (score -1):

There is something really odd about your question.

I have a [Raspberry Pi 4 with IBM MQ v9.2.1](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6414) installed and I created 2 queue managers on the Raspberry Pi 4.  I installed [MQ Visual Edit for Raspberry Pi](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6454) on the Raspberry Pi 4 (running locally).  I can get and put messages (locally) using MQ Visual Edit against the locally running queue managers.  I tried message sizes of 1MB, 10MB & 100MB without running out of memory.

Note: [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html) is a Java/MQ application.

So, if a simple Raspberry Pi can handle it, then I wonder about your configuration.

Did you use the JVM parameter of "-Xmx" to increase the maximum amount of memory that the JVM will use?  Why don't you try using "-Xmx1024" and see if it runs properly.

Comment: Hi Roger, actually I need the spring boot application to run within 40MB . I have set the property -Xmx40m

Comment: Most JVMs running a hello world application will use 20MB to 25MB.  Now add a JMS framework and Spring Boot, I don't see how it will ever run within 40MB.  Why are you trying to set the maximum memory to an extremely low value?